# Stock Availability goes To Out-Of Stock on Save

Tags: stock

Whenever I go into the Catalog and change a products Stock Availability to In Stock and save the product still keeps the Out of Stock status and doesn't change that value on the front end nor the database.

Whenever I go into the database and change the stock _status value to 1 and then proceed to go into the admin for that product it reverts back to out of stock (0).

Any clues what could be causing this? The only extensions I'm using are the Unirgy Dropship.

Edit: I've re-indexed several times and whenever I try to change quantity that goes to 0 on save as well.

Comment: DO you fill in a qty for the product? If the qty is 0 the product goes out of stock.

Comment: Probably try to do Reindex Stokc inventory and check again, becuause stock information also stored in other tables

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the quantity available field is set to 0. In this condition even if the product is set to in stock it reverts to out of stock.

Either fill in the quantity of the product or disable inventory management for the product

Answer (score 1):

Go To

> Catalog > Manage Products> >Any product > Inventory

Check inventory settings. For instance you can set use

> Manage Stock

to No.